# Edit text in checkout(DebitPayment extension )

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout

I'm using the DebitPayment extension for my german store. The problem is now, that it won't translate the text to german and I'm using the german FireGento extension. How can I translate the text to german for my german storeview? 
[image]

You can see that there is still the standard english text(I added the german text in the configuration menu but I need to translate the standard text)

[image]

On the last site of my checkout it's called Cash On Delivery but as you can see above I already changed it to "Nachnahme"(german word) How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tired translating the string through your theme.

If you add a translate.csv file under
app/design/frontend/MYTHEME/default/locale/de_DE/translate.csv

Then open this if excel for example you can then add your string to first cell

Cash On Delivery

Then to the next cell to the right of this add your translation

After you have added this file and added your translation clear all caches.

Comment: works for the second picture. TY Sir but I still need help for the first one!

Comment: Ok found a solution if you gonna use static value's for the fee just comment the php code in your default\template\msp_cashondelivery\form.phtml file  out

Comment: I would suggest adding the modules template file to your theme rather than editing the default, this will ensure you wont lose the change if you ever come to upgrading the extension